# How to design a schematic diagram of amplifier that can drive 8 ohms 0.25 Watts speaker?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, components, schematics, bjt

I have here a schematic diagram for amplifier that drives a 0.025watts 8ohms speaker. But what I need is an amplifier that drives a 0.25 watts 8 ohms speaker.

[image]

So, here are my concerns:

1. How can I possibly raise the Av to 7?
2. What is the function of R1? Is it really that necessary?
3. What are the biases and configuration use in the schematic?
4. What parameters do I need to consider in designing an amplifier?

Comment: What's the reason only BJTs, diodes, and passive components are allowed?

Comment: I don't know the actual reason why our professor won't allow us to use other components except the one I mentioned. -.-

Comment: @Kaiju19 so to be clear, what you are asking us to do is your homework, with no demonstration of initial effort on your part?

Comment: Of course not. To be clear, I just want you to enlighten me on how will I start on designing the amplifier. I just need some tips on how can I decide what configuration and biasing is perfect to use for the ampli. And how can I compute and decide for the values of the components to be use. Thank You.

Comment: @Kaiju19 in that case, you will really need to focus the question on specifically what about this problem you don't understand. A schematic would be nice, especially since you are referencing specific components ("Is it necessary that I put Rs before C1?") without any specific circuit.

Comment: @PhilFrost thank you for your concern sir. I've edited my question and added the schematic diagram. I will be very grateful to you if you can take a look at it again and if possible you can share your insights. :)

Comment: Ad 2) See [this answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/92876/8627). If you leave it out the amplification will be much higher and very frequency dependent due to C1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to focus on the points in the question: -

- Power output 0.25 watts into an 8-ohm load from a 3 volt supply
- Input is a sinewave at 1kHz
- AC gain is about 7
- Only BJTs, diodes, and passive components are allowed

If you have a 3 volt supply, in a simple circuit, the biggest voltage you can produce is 3 Vp-p. This is a sinewave, as per the detail in the question and therefore the RMS of the sinewave is going to be: -

\$\dfrac{3 Vp-p}{2\sqrt2}\$ = 1.06 Vrms.

Into 8 ohms this produces a power of 141 mW i.e not enough to satisfy the professor. This likely means using a transformer output. You could design it using a H bridge configuration bet this is probably more complicated.

Here is a class A transformer amplifier: -

[image]

Using a 1:1 transformer will do the job because the maximum swing on the collector is twice the supply rail so immediately you can generate something in the order of 5.6 Vp-p. I'm not saying 6 Vp-p because the BJT will likely saturate at 0.2V and this gets doubled when analysing the ac peak to peak voltage the circuit could produce.

5.6 Vp-p gives you a potential sinewave power of about 0.49 watts.

As you are a relative novice, I'd consider going down this route as you can get gain and sufficient drive to the loudspeaker (\$R_L\$ in the diagram) from this circuit.

As this is a homework question I'll not go into any more detail and leave it to you to do some more research on the circuit. Good luck.